# variable value in WHERE clause and wildcard

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am searching since two hours, but can't find a solution. I want to make an easy query which should check if the String `m_sName` contains a `String` variable. I have tried many things but can't find the right syntax. Using a variable works and using wildcards works too, but both together don't work.

```
TypedQuery<Kunde> query; 
query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Kunde p" + 
    " WHERE p.m_sName LIKE :name", Kunde.class);
m_lKunde = query.setParameter("name", m_sSearch).getResultList();
```

This query actually works, but I don't now how to use wildcards now. I tried `*,_,%` characters but nothing worked.

Comment: Can you try: `query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Kunde p WHERE p.m_sName LIKE '%' || :name || '%'", Kunde.class);`

Comment: Does JPQL possess SQL's concatenate operator? I never saw that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append/Prefix the wildcard symbol to the token your passing in:

```
m_lKunde = query.setParameter("name", "%" + m_sSearch + "%").getResultList();
```

Comment: @kai Glad I could help.  Please accept if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help

```
"SELECT p FROM Kunde p WHERE p.m_sName LIKE '%'|| :name || '%' ", Kunde.class);
```

Comment: Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT p FROM Kunde p WHERE p.m_sName LIKE '%'|| :name || '%'], line 1, column 46: unexpected token [|]

Comment: That is because JPQL doesn't allow you to use SQL's concatenate operator.